# How to deselect selected cell in QTableWidget by clicking on it again?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I am trying to deselect a selected cell in QTableWidget by clicking on it again. I don't know if I missed an option or a signal in documentation (I hope not). I tried with signals `cellClicked` and `cellActivated`. None of them work. Thing is, if a cell is in a deselected state and I click on it, by the time signal `cellClicked` is emitted, cell already has selection. So I cannot check for selection in a slot that reacts to that signal.

So how can I deselect a selected cell? Selection mode is `SingleSelection`. I just hope I don't have to subclass `QTableWidget`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) you can deselect a cell when pressing Ctrl during the click.

Comment: True, but I don't want that. I want that user is able to click on a selected cell and deselect it with that click. Basically, when you click white cell, it becomes blue (selected). When you click blue cell, it becomes white again (deselected).

Comment: Isn't [`setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) what you want?

Comment: Similar. But now user can select multiple cells. I want user to be able to select **only one** cell and deselect it by clicking it again. Also, highlight should be removed too (since Qt differentiates between full selection and highlighting - with `MultiSelection` highlighting stays).

Comment: If none of the standard selection modes provide what you want you'll probably have to implement it yourself by connecting to either the [`QTableWidget::cellClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked) or [`QTableWidget::itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#itemClicked) signals.

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the question, problem with `cellClicked` (and now I tried `itemClicked` - it is same) is that the state of selection is set before the signal is emitted. So when I check in my slot if it is selected it will be. And when I call `clearSelection` in that `if` it will deselect it. So the end result when I click a cell is: it selects and then immediately deselects itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've only performed minimal testing but the following appears to do what you want...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTableWidget tw(5, 10);

  /*
   * Disable any normal selection mode.
   */
  tw.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);

  QObject::connect(&tw, &QTableWidget::cellClicked,
                   [&tw](int row, int col)
                     {

                       /*
                        * Make sure we have an item in the cell.
                        */
                       auto *item = tw.itemAt(row, col);
                       if (!item) {
                         item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("cell[%1, %2]").arg(row).arg(col));
                         tw.setItem(row, col, item);
                       }

                       /*
                        * Update selection based on current state.
                        */
                       bool was_selected = item->isSelected();
                       tw.selectionModel()->clear();
                       item->setSelected(!was_selected);
                     });
  tw.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. Thank you.